# AngularJS Scope variable Unwatch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to unwatch one Angular scope variable after certain point in program.

Here is what I am following.

```
$scope.oldVar = {data: "Something"}
$scope.blankArray = []
$scope.blankArray.push($scope.oldVar)
```

Now whatever changes I am doing to $scope.oldVar, It is reflecting the changes to blankArray which I am viewing on Screen.

Is there any way in angular to restrict that?

Comment: I found some article with a workaround for your scenario: https://coderwall.com/p/d_aisq/speeding-up-angularjs-s-digest-loop

Comment: This is because `oldVar` is reference type variable. And you push the reference of it to the array. You simply can do this:
`$scope.blankArray.push({ data: $scope.oldVar.data })`;

Answer (score 0):

## Use angular.copy

You can use `angular.copy` to create a new copy of the data. This would prevent the data from being bound within `blankArray`.

So at some point in your application, to unbind the values, you can use `angular.copy`.

```
$scope.blankArray = angular.copy($scope.blankArray)
```

### Here Be Dragons

The problem with unbinding a value is that you'll be introducing complexity as your controller now needs to be aware of when the value is bound and when it isn't bound. This introduces an extra state to manage and all your logic now needs to have this awareness.

### Demonstration

```js
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.oldVar = {data: "Something"};
    $scope.blankArray = [];
    $scope.blankArray.push($scope.oldVar);
    $scope.withoutCopy = []
    $scope.withoutCopy.push($scope.oldVar);
    
    $scope.change = function() {
        $scope.oldVar.data = Math.random();
    };
  
    $scope.unbind = function() {
        $scope.blankArray = angular.copy($scope.blankArray);
    };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="ctrl">
    <button ng-click="change()">Test</button>
    <button ng-click="unbind()">Unbind</button>
    <pre>{{ blankArray | json }}</pre>
    <pre>{{ oldVar | json }}</pre>
    <pre>{{ withoutCopy | json }}</pre>
</div>
```